# How to write a volume label into a variable the right way?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wanna save the volume label into the variable `%volume%`.
The normal Syntax would be:

```
C:\Users\volk>for /f "tokens=1-5*" %%1 in ('vol C:') do set volume=%%6
```

This way I get an syntax error that says `%%1 was unexpected at this time`.
So I tried a different solution:

```
C:\Users\volk>for /f "tokens=1-5*" %1 in ('vol C:') do set volume=%6

C:\Users\volk>set volume=System

C:\Users\volk>set volume=
```

But this way `%volume%` is filled with `System` and in the next step overwritten
with 'nothing' (variable is empty and not existing again). 
I´m working in a Windows 8 PE(dont´t know if it´s important for a solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=5,*" %a in ('vol C:') do set volume=%b
```

works for me. If you get a second `set`command, just filter out the needed lines:

```
for /f "tokens=5,*" %a in ('vol C:^|find ":"') do set volume=%b
```

Note:  `%x` is for use at the command prompt. Inside a batch file you need to use `%%x`

Answer (score 0):

Try to distinguish SET outputs by adding suffix to a variable name, like:

```
for /f "tokens=1-5*" %1 in ('vol C:') do set volume%2=%6
```

As long as you can consistently identify this suffix in a 'vol C:' output, you know the variable name storing your Volume name.
In my case %2="in", so my desired variable names "volumein".